# can you make "Storage Metrics" page public viewable?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

can you make the Site Collection Administration\Storage Metrics (_layouts/storman.aspx) pages viewable to **non** site admins?

it would be great if users can see themselves how much space their (sub)sites/libraries use.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the permissions of a layouts page.

However, the Storage Metrics page (Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.StorageMetricsPage) inherits all of its permissions settings directly from Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.LayoutsPageBase. This means the `RequireSiteAdministrator` property is false and the `RightsRequired` property is set to the default.

Here is the definition for the default rights:

```
public static readonly SPBasePermissions DefaultLayoutsRights = 
    SPBasePermissions.ViewFormPages | 
    SPBasePermissions.Open | 
    SPBasePermissions.ViewPages;
```

Any non-administrator users who met that criteria should have access to the page.

Comment: sorry, i'm no expert in the SharePoint Foundation Class Libraries and don't have access to the server directly.
can i change this property from SharePoint Designer? (i'm member of the Site Collection Administrators)

Comment: There are not any changes you can make to the page. You need to make sure your users have enough permissions, which can be done through the UI.

Comment: Is there a page (MS or blog even) that lists the RequireSiteAdministrator and RightRequired properties for all the pages in the layouts directory? -OR- how would I find these properties for a given page if I had a question or requirement to let someone see a given page?

Comment: @CodeJockey: I suggest asking that as a new question